# Trying to pass state through link - React

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, state

I can't figure out why I cannot pass state from component ArrayList to ArrayList2. Can anyone chime in and offer a solution to the problem. I think I've exhausted every SO thread, YouTube video and Google search on the subject and I keep getting the following error message,

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'message' of 'location.state' as it is null.".

My code is as follows:

Component 1

```
import "./App.css";
import ArrayList from "./ArrayList";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ArrayList2 from "./dataFolder/ArrayList2";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="*" element={<ArrayList />} />
        <Route exact path="/2" element={<ArrayList2 />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Component 2

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Years from "./dataFolder/Years";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

function ArrayList() {
  const years = Years;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <nav>
        <ul className="no-bullets">
          {years.map((item) => (
            <Link
              className="no-link-style"
              to={{
                pathname: "/2",
                state: { message: "This is a passed Item" },
              }}
            >
              <li>{item}</li>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ArrayList;
```

Component 3

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import ArrayList from "../ArrayList";
import NavBar from "../NavBar";

function ArrayList2(props) {
  const types = ["General", "Primary"];

  const location = useLocation();
  const { message } = props.location.state;

  console.log(message)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <ul className="no-bullets">
        {types.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ArrayList2;
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `const { message } = location.state`

Comment: add sample  in https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the first code block, you are not passing any prop to **ArrayList** component, you are passing it to Link prop. Without passing a prop to the ArrayList component you are trying to access it. This leads to destructuring of an `undefined` value. You can use the passed route parameters by using the `useParams` hook that is defined in the react-router package.